# Find and Replace Certain Values w/ VBA

Tags: excel, vba, replace, find

I'm new to VBA but I hope anyone could help me.
I want to find the values of Img1.(from I8 to K10) in Sheet1 (Col.A) which is a list of different users and replace their corresponding value in Col.F to a 1.

Im trying to do it using Vba but I dont know how to code it.

Img1. The values that I want to find in Sheet 1

[image]

Img2. Find the given user in Img1 and change their value of Col.F to 1

[image]

Comment: Im trying to use VBA in Excel but I don´t know what to code

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like my code below. You'll need to update the table, sheet, and range names to fit your example.

```
Sub findvalues()
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With

    Dim dict As Object
    Dim dict2 As Object
    Dim anArr As Variant
    Dim r As Range
    Dim r2 As Range
    Dim rC As Range
    Dim nRc As Range
    
    Set r = Sheets(3).Range("I8:K10")
    Set nRc = Sheets(3).ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns(1).Range
     
     Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    For Each rC In r
            If rC.Value <> "" Then
                    On Error Resume Next
                       dict.Add rC.Value, 1
                End If
                 On Error GoTo 0
    Next rC
     
     Set dict2 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    For Each rC2 In nRc
            If rC2.Value <> "" Then
            IsInArray = Not IsError(Application.match(rC2.Value, dict.keys(), 0))
                If IsInArray = True Then
                    On Error Resume Next
                       dict2.Add rC2.Address, 1
                End If
                 On Error GoTo 0
            End If
    Next rC2
    
    anArr = Join(dict2.keys(), ",")
    anArr = Replace(anArr, "$", "")
    
    If Len(anArr) > 253 Then
        For Each it In dict2.keys()
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Range(it).Offset(, 5) = 1
        Next it
        Else
        Sheets(3).Range(anArr).Offset(, 5) = 1
    End If

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    End With
end sub
```

Edit:

If you are not interested in using `On Error Resume Next`, you can edit the code below for your purposes

```
With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
  For Each it In Array("aa1", "aa2", "aa1", "aa3", "aa4", "aa2")
    If Not .Exists(it) Then .Add it, it & "_content"
  Next
End With
```

Edit2: The biggest issue with the code above was not accounting for the 255 character limit imposed on .range(). So, I created a workaround in the above code. On ~8K rows it ran 0.4 seconds.

Comment: Note that `Dim r, r2, rC, nRc As Range` only declares `nRc As Range` but all the others as `Variant`. In VBA you need to specify a type for **every** variable `Dim r As Range, r2 As Range, rC As Range, nRc As Range` otherwise it is `Variant` by default! • Same for `Dim dict, dict2 As Object`.

Comment: Good to know. I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: Instead of `On Error Resume Next` I recommend to use `dict.Exists`. Running into an error exception (and catch it) comes with a lot higher cost then checking the existance of the value. It is always a better sollution not to use `On Error Resume Next` if it is possible.

Comment: That I did know, but I haven't broken into the dict.exists section yet. I did read about it, but I didn't think the code would be necessary.

Comment: I was just mentioning because on large datasets this will have an impact on speed (which might be a point for some people looking for a solution).

Comment: I added it in case someone is interest in that code.

Comment: Thank you very much, the code worked perfectly. :)